# Summing sections of a 2d array python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2d array with dimensions `array[x][9]`. X because its reading from a file of varying length. I want to find the sum of each column of the array but for 24  columns at a time and input the results into a new array; equivalent to `sum(array2[0:24])` but for a 2d array. Is there a special syntax i just dont know about or do i have to do it manually.  I know if it was a 1d array i could iterate through it by doing

```
for x in range(len(array)/24):
     total.append(sum(array2[x1:x24])) # so i get an array of the sums
```

What is the equivalent for a 2d array and doing it column by column. I can imagine doing it by storing each column in its own separate 1d array and then finding the sums, or a mess of for and while loops. Neither of which sound even slightly elegant.

Comment: ... _sum of each column of the array but for 24 columns at a time_ ... don't you mean rows? because `array[x][9]` means there are only 9 columns.

Comment: yes rows, my mistake

Comment: Do you need the sum for each of the 9 columns separately?

Comment: yes. each column needs to be separate. the output needs to be in the same format as the input just 1/24 as many rows but technically each item being 24 times larger.

Comment: `zip(*alst)` can be used 'transpose' a list of lists.  That may make your 'column' sum easier.  If the sublists are all the same length `numpy` arrays might be more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you perhaps are working with time series data, with a file containing hourly values and you want a daily sum (hence the `24`). The pandas library will do this really nicely:

Suppose you have your data in `data.csv`:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
```

If one of your columns was a timestamp, you could use that, but if you only have raw data, you can create a time index:

```
df.index = pandas.date_range(pandas.datetime.today().date(), 
                             periods=df.shape[0], freq='H')
```

Now the summing of all columns on daily basis is very easy:

```
daily = df.resample('D').apply(sum)
```

Comment: This is exactly it. I can get the timestamp with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to transpose your array and use a comprehension to sum each column separately:

```
>>> array = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]]
>>> [sum(a) for a in zip(*array)]
[111, 222, 333]
```

Comment: summing the columns isnt the difficult part its doing 24 at a time that im having a problem with

Comment: @Sam The code in the answer works for any constant number of columns,

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
x = len(a) # x is the length of a

step = 24

# get the number of iterations you need to do
n = int(math.ceil(float(x) / step))


new_a = [map(lambda k: sum(list(k)), zip(*a[i * step:(i + 1) * step])) 
         for i in range(0, n)]
```

If `x` is not a multiple of `24` then the last row in the `new_a` will have the sum of remainder rows (count of which will be less that 24).

This also assumes that the values in `a` are numbers so I have not done any conversions.